# Nesta articles summaries. Cut tag in haml pages

Tags: nestacms

Is there any way to avoid duplication of summaries and first paragraphs or the article for `.haml` pages? Now I have to copy and paste them every time.

The ideal case is to use  to split the article with read_more link.

Answer (score 1):

Nesta's author here... Sorry, I've not been monitoring SO for Nesta stuff. I'll start doing that.

Did you see the Foldable plugin? I think it does pretty much what you want.

http://nestacms.com/docs/plugins/foldable

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
%cut
```

tag in your articles and change your main part of `/view/summaries.haml` as follows:

```
- pages.each do |page|
  %li
    %article
      %header
        %h1
          %a(href="#{path_to(page.abspath)}")= page.link_text
      - if page.summary.nil? || page.summary.empty?
        - cut = page.body(self).split('<cut>')
        ~ cut.first
        -if cut.size > 1
          %p.read_more
            %a(href="#{path_to(page.abspath)}")= page.read_more
      - else
        ~ page.summary
        %p.youtube
          %a(href="#{path_to(page.abspath)}")= page.read_more
      = haml :page_meta, :layout => false, :locals => { :page => page }
```

Everything above %cut tag will be displayed as summary on articles page.